# Laravel 5.1 random logins to application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

For some reason some people get loggedin to a random user in the users table in my Laravel 5.1 application.

I can't figure out what it is. Tried all Session drivers. Currently I'm on the database session drive, because I can easily clear it then.

When it occurs by someone, the website owner contacts me, but I can't reproduce it myself. When I get the sign it happened again I clear the Session table in the database and run `php artisan auth:clear-resets` on the server.

Most visitors that are loggedin already, are visiting the website for the first time. It happened on both Windows and Osx, and in Chrome and IE as far as I know about.

I use https://github.com/laravel/socialite - thought that was the problem, but people also get loggedin as users that didnt' register via SocialMedia.

Probably there is something wrong in my Authentication code.. But what? I rewrote the Login-part, but that looks fine as far I can see.

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/authenticate', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticateLogin');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::post('auth/email', 'Auth\AuthController@emailChecker');
Route::get('auth/{socialite}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{socialite}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

The AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use App\User;
use App\Social;

use Auth;
use Socialite;
use Validator;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout']]);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Socialite authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $socialite)
    {
]       return Socialite::driver($socialite)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Socialite.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($socialite)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($socialite)->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $socialite);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    private function findOrCreateUser($provider, $socialite)
    {
        if ($authUser = Social::whereSecret($provider->id)->first()) {
            return User::findOrFail($authUser->user_id);
        }

        if($user = User::whereEmail($provider->email)->first())
        {
            $user = $user;
        }
        else
        {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => @$provider->name,
                'email' => $provider->email,
                'password' => bcrypt(md5($provider->id)),
            ]);
        }

        $social = Social::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'secret' => $provider->id,
            'provider' => $socialite,
        ]);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create($data);
    }

    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticateLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if(User::whereEmail($request->get('email'))->firstOrFail())
        {
            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')], @$request->get('remember')))
            {
                return route('dashboard');
            }
            return abort(403);
        }
    }

    public function updateLastLogin(User $ser)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->last_login = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
    }

}
```

And I have a listener in the eventsServicePrvider that does no harm I guess:

```
protected $listen = [
    'auth.login' => ['\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@updateLastLogin'],
];
```

Anyone seeing the bug? Or tips how to debug this? I can't figure out how it can happen..

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=redis

Comment: What's that `]` in your `AuthController::redirectToProvider()` method?

Comment: Could you please clarify as to when the issue happens. Suppose a user logs in to your page. Then, the user is logged in as a different user? Or does it happen at random when visiting some pages on your website? For debugging I personally use `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`. Maybe here you can find some hints on what is actually going on (i.e. examining the DB queries).

Comment: @daniela occurs sometimes, for some users; totally random. only happens on production, not on local.
.arcesilas thats a function from the socialite package

Comment: Does the random user assignment take place after login? Or may it also occur before login? Do you use different PHP versions on your local machine and on your production server? Why do you use the @ sign in `@$request->get('remember')` when calling `Auth::attempt`?

Comment: Regarding Arcesilas comment, the closing bracket seems to be a typo. Is that a typo just in your question, or in your production code as well?

Comment: @Daniela typo - and also type that i used the @

Comment: Please, put here your session database dump.

Comment: @CavidAliyev it's in redis, not database stored. and wouldnt that be unsafe to dump it here?

Comment: Do you have any kind of caching in place? Inside laravel or in front of it, e.g. varnish?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have not any mistake with your auth code. The wrong is consist of that when user is authentificated it creates duplicate session value in redis. In result of this system mix user's ID and one user sign in with different name. And to be able to prevent of this case use keys of type SET. Each key will only contain one value (member) instead of the usual usage of sets to hold, well, sets.

That way, whenever you try to create a key that its session exists already, Redis will refuse. Whenever you try to create a value to a given key where that value already exists as a member of the key's set, Redis will refuse as well.